# Unit/Jest test with bootstrap vue Fail

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I got this error when I try to run a test on bootstrap vue components: 
**"ReferenceError: BootstrapVue is not defined"**
In the .spec.js file I added this:

```
  import TableSummary from "@/components/TableSummary";
  import { createLocalVue, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

   const localVue = createLocalVue();

   localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

   describe('TableSummary', ()=> {
     test('if the user is typing, the button becomes enabled', async ()=> {
       const wrapper = mount(TableSummary, { localVue });
       wrapper.setData({isDisabled: true});
       await wrapper.vm.$nextTick;
       expect(wrapper.find('input').state.isDisabled).toBe(false);
     });
   });
```

I ran the same instructions as a correct answer here on stack overflow but still, it doesn't work for me... I couldn't comment on the answer as I am not level 50, and I had to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import the BootstrapVue

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
```

Comment: Welcome to stakeoverflow, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how so works. guide - [how can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [how to ans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  for any other help [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: can you please showcase this in code if no error is there or explain it further